# swift ios mobile app login submit

Tags: ios, swift, web-applications

I'm trying to program an iOS application for this website of our university: https://uniworx.ifi.lmu.de/

I failed with the login. I have managed it to send a http submit for the login form, but I always get the same site back as response. I want to get the site you normally see **after** logging in. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code of my function:

```
 func newTest()
{
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://uniworx.ifi.lmu.de/?action=uniworxLoginDo")! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "username=myusername&password=mypassword"
    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil && data != nil else {                                                          
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse , httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {          
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
        }

        let responseString = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")


    }
    task.resume()




}
```

I've changed my real username and password in the code -of course-.

Comment: Did you try to check your url if it is valid?

Answer (score 1):

Try this I hope it would be helpful for you!!

In Swift 2+

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://uniworx.ifi.lmu.de/?action=uniworxLoginDo")!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    let postString = "Username=Yourusername&password=Yourpassword"
    request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
        guard error == nil && data != nil else {                                                          // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
        }

        let responseString = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")
    }
    task.resume()
```

In Swift 3 You can

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://uniworx.ifi.lmu.de/?action=uniworxLoginDo")!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
let postString = "Username=Yourusername&password=Yourpassword"
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
        print("error=\(error)")
        return
    }

    if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
        print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
        print("response = \(response)")
    }

    let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    print("responseString = \(responseString)")
}
task.resume()
```