# HTTP Send Request Parameter in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlrequest

i want to send request with username and password for getting authentication key from server, here is my code, i don't know how send to parameter with request, please help me for solve it.

```
let urlString = "http://services.84069.ir/Restful/PaymentService.svc/authenticate"
func recentProfileURL(parameter : [String:String]?) -> NSURL {

    let component = NSURLComponents(string: urlString)!
    var queryItem = [NSURLQueryItem]()
    if let param = parameter {
        for (key,value) in param {
            let item = NSURLQueryItem(name: key, value: value)
            queryItem.append(item)
        }
    }
    component.queryItems = queryItem
    return component.URL!
}

func fetchCode(completion completion: (ProfileResult) -> Void){

    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: recentProfileURL(["UserName": self.userNameParam]))

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error)  in

        let result = self.processUserProfileRequest(data: data, error: error)
    completion(result)
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

I'm trying send username and password for getting authentication code from server how can send array of parameter instead of one parameter?

Comment: Try this maybe it would be useful for you!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40108462/swift-ios-mobile-app-login-submit/40108876#40108876

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: ""http://services.84069.ir/Restful/PaymentService.svc/authenticate"))

var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

var params = ["UserName":"UserName you wish to send", "password":"Password you wish to send"] as Dictionary<String, String>

var err: NSError?

request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &err)

var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
    print("Response: \(response)")`

}
```

Comment: i have an this error when using your suggestion : JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.

Answer (score 0):

Try this I hope it would be helpful for you!!

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://example.com/login.php")!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
let postString = "Username=Yourusername&password=Yourpassword"
request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
    guard error == nil && data != nil else {                                                          // check for fundamental networking error
        print("error=\(error)")
        return
    }

    if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
        print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
        print("response = \(response)")
    }

    let responseString = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    print("responseString = \(responseString)")
}
task.resume()
```

Comment: my response should be {"ErrorCode":0,"ErrorMessage":"","Result":1,"AuthKey":"50_7476070793275070744414070707641070724131070235735070714812070238280701410440702975070464736070567130070702745070137545070442569070243973070"} but this suggestion throw anerror

Comment: this result is JSON type ? when type url in safari show this message : Method not allowed.

Comment: @ava May be the chance of your requesting url string is not correct check once again what ur is requesting

Comment: @ava This code is perfectly working on my pc if you are getting error regarding url then check and last one thing you should check also APP Transport security setting in info.plist

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126398/discussion-between-sanjeet-verma-and-ava).

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```html
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://www.thisismylink.com/postName.php")!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
let postString = "id=13&name=Jack"
request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
    guard error == nil && data != nil else {                                                          // check for fundamental networking error
        print("error=\(error)")
        return
    }

    if let httpStatus = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse where httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
        print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
        print("response = \(response)")
    }

    let responseString = String(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    print("responseString = \(responseString)")
}
task.resume()
```